# Finite modules over finite local rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite commutative local ring with identity. If $M$ is a finite $R$-module it is necessarily projective?

Comment: Do you mean $R$ is finite-dimensional? Over local rings projective is equivalent to free.

Comment: No, $R$ is a finite ring. Yes, over local rings projective is equivalent to free by a Theorem of Kaplansky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime number.
Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $M = R/pR$.
Since the number of elements of $M$ is $p$, $M$ cannot be free.
Hence $M$ cannot be projective.

Answer (score 5):

As Andrew pointed out, every finitely-generated projective module over a local ring is free (in fact, the hypothesis of being finitely-generated can be dropped - this is a theorem of Kaplansky). Hence, it remains to show that there exists a non-free module. But we have the following characterisation:

A commutative ring $R$ is a field if and only if every module is free.

For a concrete example: if $R$ is a commutative ring which is not a field, let $I$ be a non-zero proper ideal. Then $R/I$ is module, which is not free (its annihilator is $I$).

Answer (score 1):

Direct counter-example: Let $R=\mathbb F_p[t]/(t^2),M=\mathbb F_p = R/(t).$ Then $M$ is finite but not free, as $M$ is torsion with $Ann(M)=(t).$

Comment: I can understand your argument, but I won't say that $M$ is torsion as long as $t$ is a zero-divisor in $R$. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_(algebra)#Definition.)