# Why $\mathbb{Z}_p$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ cannot be free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finite-rings

Makoto Kato in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180431/finite-modules-over-finite-local-rings) wrote:

> Let $p$ be a prime number.
>   Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$.
>   Let $M = R/pR$.
>   Since the number of elements of $M$ is $p$, $M$ cannot be free.
>   Hence $M$ cannot be projective.

I cannot conclude that $M$ cannot be free.

Comment: In the finite case, $M$ is free means $M$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $n$ copies of $R$. Since $M$ has $p$ elements, it cannot contain a copy of $R$.

Comment: @Levent Thanks. I felt that it is some easy conclusion, but I was thinking about different (but equivalent) definition of freeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $px=0$ for all $x\in M$, and $p\neq0_R$, we see that every non-empty subset of $M$ is linearly dependent over $R$. But $M$ is not generated by the empty set, so it cannot be free.

Comment: Thanks for alternative proof. In the beginning I was thinking about such kind of argument.